# Unsubscribe Xamarin Messaging Center iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am using Xamarin's Messaging Center to send back a notice from a photo utility class when a response is given back that a photo uploaded successfully to the server.

**ViewModel**

```
public constructor
{

    var photoUtility = new PhotoUtility();
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Helper_PhotoUtility, string>(this, "UploadedNotifier", (sender, value) =>
                {
                //do some updates to the photo's status
                }


}
```

**PhotoUtility**

```
Private UploadFinished()
{
    MessagingCenter.Send<Helper_PhotoUtility, string>(this, "UploadedNotifier", PhotosGUIDPK);
}
```

Everything was working great in Android as attaching the XAML's code behind OnAppearing / OnDisappearing was only called once. However in iOS those events would be called every time the UI gave way to the Camera. This lead to a small problem with the messaging center being unsubscribed during picture taking.

I read that you can just move everything to the constructor and call the unsubscribe first but that seems pretty hacky.

Does anyone know of a way to reliably subscribe/unsubscribe to messaging center within a View Models normal life cycle reliably without depending on a non Xamarin supported framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally do that setup from the constructor (or from a method called from the constructor).  If you feel that is hacky, then a simple alternative would be to use a bool as a sentinel to check whether you had already setup the subscription.

```
bool subscribed = false;

protected override void OnAppearing() {

  if (!subscribed) {
    // setup messaging
    subscribed = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: If I sentinel OnAppearing when do I unsubscribe? Unsubscribing in OnDisappearing  will still leave me with no subscriber while the camera is in the foreground on iOS. If i dont unsubscribe at all I could end up with multiple subscriptions if they leave and come back to this viewmodel. Unless I am mistaken in thinking Messaging Center subscriptions live beyond the scope of the class subscribing.

Comment: I generally don't worry about unsubscribing and haven't run into any problems.  I can't say for sure there aren't cons to that approach, but I haven't seen them.

Comment: Guess I will have to test it. If the subscriber does not hold a reference that keeps the class in memory then that solves my problem. I still dont like the idea of unsubscribing from an event that may or may not have been subscribed to but it is an answer.

Comment: @Jason If you don't unsubscribe, number of calling will be increased every time you create object.

Answer (score 0):

The above example is helpful, but I still ran into an oversubscription scenario after launching the page several times because I wasn't unsubscribing anywhere. If I implemented the sample code above, every time I pushed my page on the navigation stack I ended up with an additional subscription to the same signature in MessageCenter. 
In the code below I'm setting AddedPageOrModalToNav = true every time I push a page or modal from the view model.

```
          private readonly NavigationPage _navPage = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
    private bool _viewModelSubscribed;
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        if (!_viewModelSubscribed)
        {
            ViewModel.SubscribeMessages();
            _viewModelSubscribed = true;
            _navPage.PoppedToRoot += NavPage_PoppedToRoot;
        }
        base.OnAppearing();
    }

    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        if (ViewModel.AddedPageOrModalToNav)
        {
            ViewModel.AddedPageOrModalToNav = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (!ViewModel.AddedPageOrModalToNav)
            {
               _navPage.PoppedToRoot -= NavPage_PoppedToRoot;
                ViewModel.UnsubscribeMessages();
                _viewModelSubscribed = false;
            }
        }

        base.OnDisappearing();
    }

    void NavPage_PoppedToRoot(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        _navPage.PoppedToRoot -= NavPage_PoppedToRoot;
        ViewModel.UnsubscribeMessages();
        _viewModelSubscribed = false;
    }
```